# Why is my LinkedHashSet empty within the toString() method?

Tags: java, tostring

I have a simple class extending `LinkedHashSet` and am trying to override the `toString()` method.  I've added some elements to the `Set` in the main method, however within my `toString` method, the `Set` is empty.  The code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MyHashSet<T> extends LinkedHashSet<T>{
    private Set <T> myHashSet;


    public MyHashSet (){
        myHashSet = new HashSet<T>(5);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
         if (myHashSet.isEmpty())
            return "This MyHashSet is empty.";
         else
            return myHashSet.toString();
    }

    public static void main (String[] args){
         MyHashSet <String> myHashSet = new MyHashSet<>();

         myHashSet.add("A");
         myHashSet.add("B");
         myHashSet.add("C");
         myHashSet.add("D");
         myHashSet.add("E");

         System.out.println(myHashSet);

         System.out.println(myHashSet.isEmpty());
    }
}
```

returns the following:

> This MyHashSet is empty.
>   
>   false

I'm expecting `toString()` to instead return

> [A, B, C, D, E]

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: you have **two** things in your code called `myHashSet`.

Comment: Five minutes in a debugger and this question (and the consequent downvote) would not have been necessary :)

Comment: myHashSet.myHashSet.add("A"); : Add data in this format.

Comment: @PavelHoral Comments like this are not helpful, unless you actually _start_ describing these things.  This question was asked in good faith, and you are expected to [Be Nice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: You got my vote - simply because you put up a full [mcve] including expected and actual output. Have fun voting yourself now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toString()` method relies on the `myHashSet` field you are declaring but you don't add elements in .

Indeed, here :

```
     MyHashSet <String> myHashSet = new MyHashSet<>();

     myHashSet.add("A");
     myHashSet.add("B");
     myHashSet.add("C");
     myHashSet.add("D");
     myHashSet.add("E");
```

You add the elements by relying on the `LinkedHashSet` implementation that your class inherits from. And it of course doesn't use your field.

In fact, you don't even need declare `myHashSet` if you extend `LinkedHashSet`.
So just the change the `toString()` method to rely on the class you inherit from :

```
@Override
public String toString(){
     if (isEmpty())
        return "This MyHashSet is empty.";
     else
        return super.toString();
}
```

Otherwise you can also use composition by relying on the `myHashSet` field but so you should not extend  `LinkedHashSet` but rather implement `Set<E>`.

**Anyway, use inheritance or composition.

But not both at the same time.**

Answer (score 3):

Simple: because you are **not** adding any elements to that **internal** map that you have as field in your class.

This here:

```
myHashSet.add("A");
```

adds element to the "set" structure that your class **inherited**.

In order to use that *internal* set, you would have to @Override the various `add()` methods as well.

But please note: you should **either** use composition (using that internal `myHashSet` field) - **or** inheritance (then you don't need such a field in the first place).

You are combining **two** concept that shouldn't be combined this way!

Beyond that: you have two things named `myHashSet` - that is rather confusing. Avoid re-using names in such ways!